# How to change the value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have this array:

```
BEGIN_BROWSER 54
msie6.0 7
safari5.0.3 5
chrome18.0.1025.308 1
firefox20.0 4
.
.
END_BROWSER
```

And in order for me to change the value i do this :

```
preg_match("/BEGIN_BROWSER(.*)END_BROWSER/is", $awstats, $matches);
            $browser = $matches[0] ;               
          //  print_array($browser);

$newline = "
"; 
            $lines = explode($newline,$browser);
            $results = array();
            foreach($lines as $line) {
                $parts = explode(" ",trim($line),2);
                if( count($parts) < 2) continue;
                else {
                   $results[$parts[0]] = intval($parts[1]);
                }
            }
           $results["InternetExplorer"] = 0;
            foreach($results as $key => $value){
              if(strpos($key,"msie") !== false){
                 $results["InternetExplorer"] += $value;
                 unset($results[$key]);
              }
            }
```

In result i get instead of `msie`=>`InternetExplorer`. Is there a way that i can change it instead to `Internet Explorer` with space between words ? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  You want to change `$results["InternetExplorer"]` to `$results["Internet Explorer"]`?

Comment: Yeah! but when i do that it doesn't change the first `msie`!

Comment: `$results["Internet Explorer"] = 0`?

Comment: I have to define the var `InternetExplorer` and initialize it !

Comment: So why you can't define `Internet Explorer` and initialize `it`?

Comment: I tried, It didn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest to replace `\n\r` with some specific character then just explode the string by that specific character because the way you used for splitting new line is not recommended.
Now for the solution try

```
$browsers = str_replace("\n\r", '~~', $awstats);
$browsers = explode('~~', $browsers);
$results = array();
$results['Internet Explorer'] = 0;
foreach($browsers as $b) {
   $parts = explode(" ",trim($b),2);
   if( count($parts) < 2) continue;
   else {
       if ($parts[0] == 'msie') {
          $results['Internet Explorer'] = $results['Internet Explorer'] + intval($parts[1]);
       }
       else {
          $results[$parts[0]] = intval($parts[1]);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do use `preg_replace` to change a string:

```
foreach($results as $key => $value){

    $key = preg_replace('/InternetExplorer/', 'Internet Explorer', $key);

    if(strpos($key,"msie") !== false){
```